# How to create not squared images using ccfits?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, fits

I'd like to create a not squared set of images using ccfits. I can make a single one in the primaryHDU, like this:

```
long axes[2] = { jmax, imax };   
std::auto_ptr<CCfits::FITS> pFits(0);
pFits.reset ( new CCfits::FITS ( "fitfile.fits", FLOAT_IMG, 2, axes ) );

std::valarray<double> h2a0array ( jmax * imax );
for ( int i = 0 ; i < imax ; i++ 
  for ( int j = 0 ; j < jmax ; j++ )
    h2a0array [ j + jmax * i ] = i + j;  

pFits->pHDU().write  ( fpixel, imax * jmax, h2a0array );
```

But I don't know how to add other not-squared images to my FITS file. I guess I have to use the CCFITS::addImage function, but can only obtain squared images using it:

```
long fpixel ( 1 );
std::vector<long> extAx ( 2, dim );
CCfits::ExtHDU* imageExt2 = pFits->addImage ( "h2a0array", FLOAT_IMG, extAx );
imageExt2->write ( fpixel, imax * jmax, h2a0array );
```

The extAx vector contains only two values, the first is the dimension (1D, 2D, 3D) of the image to add to the FITS file, the second is its size. I don't know any other way to add an image to a FITS file. If someone does, your help is strongly welcome!

Thanks,
Arnaud.

Answer (score 0):

The vector of the last argument of addImage can have any dimension
and different axis lengths in the dimensions.  There is no requirement that
the axis lengths are the same ("square" as you seem to call it):

```
vector<long> extAx ;
extAx.push_back(imax) ; 
extAx.push_back(jmax) ;
extAx.push_back(kmax) ;

pFits->addImage("h2a0array", FLOAT_IMG, extAx );
```